# Unable to save from DataGridView to SQL Server Database VB.Net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

My Data from database displays successfully to DataGridView but When i make changes in DataGridView and click the update button in the form code executes successfully and show message "update successfully"...That Means code is working properly but the problem is changes was not being saved in database...when i reload the form, it shows the old data no any changes...Here is my code

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class FormUpdate

    'Variables declared here
    Dim Con As New SqlConnection
    Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmdString As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim cmdbl As New SqlCommandBuilder

    Public Sub FormUpdate_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ShipmentDataSetDataGridView.Shipment_Main' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Shipment_MainTableAdapter2.Fill(Me.ShipmentDataSetDataGridView.Shipment_Main)

 'CONNECTION STRING FOR THE DATABASE
        Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=TARIQUE;Initial Catalog=shipment;Integrated Security=True"

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

        Try
            Con.Open()
            cmdbl = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(dt)

            MessageBox.Show("Updated successfully!")


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Con.Close()
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: I am sure not all of that code is in offense here - please reduce it to the amount that needs reviewing.

Comment: Hi @OneFineDay code edited...for your reference please see the very bottom code that i used to update button...

Comment: @Onefineday. It helps a lot to see the whole code example especially for new programmers. Please do not give this advice any more or anywhere important like SO

Comment: @webzy, the code originally supplied was too much and some of it had nothing to do with the code you see now. Please refrain from telling others what to to do regarding things you are not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the `GetUpdateCommand()`.Update method fails if this line of code is missed.

try adding `cmdb1.GetUpdateCommand()` before `da.Update(dt)`.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...Tried but getting this error: System.InvalidOperationException: The DataAdapter.SelectCommand property needs to be initialized.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: The DataAdapter.SelectCommand property needs to be initialized.

Comment: thats probably because the sqladapter is initialized with null.

Comment: Still getting the same error and sometimes sql generation error...Can you please correct and post corrected code here...

Comment: what is the code you are using to fill the dataset??

Comment: cmdString = "SELECT * FROM Shipment_Main"
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmdString, Con)
            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt